# InfoPath form that allows adding and editing multiple items

Tags: 2010, list, infopath

I have a Records List that has a custom InfoPath form that adds an item to the list. However, there are many fields in a record, and I have a requirement to allow users (instead of adding one record at a time) to select a 'template' from a drop down, see default records (1 or more) that would be created for that template, edit the records if needed, and then create all the records.

Originally I was hoping to have a "Default List" that is structured the same as the main Records list except it would have a column called 'template'.  The InfoPath form would have a drop down that listed all the possible templates.  When the user would select a template, it would pull the items from the Default List for that template and display them in editable controls (with a repeating section?) so that the user could make changes.  Then, when clicking Submit, the new records would be added to the main Records list.

I know InfoPath can display multiple records, but I cannot seem to find a definitive answer as to if you can edit multiple records at the same time and then submit them all to a list.  I have tried to add a repeating section, but when I do, I cannot find a way to add a drop down control that would list the templates (the drop down always ends up in a repeating section)

I guess my questions are, can you edit multiple items in InfoPath at the same time and then submit all changes?  Does this have to be done in a Grid-like view only?  And, if you use repeating sections, can you have controls outside of the repeater that can display options pulled from another List (a List of templates)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes it can be done. To achieve that you will need to write custom code and publish administrator approved IP form. Out of the box IP is really designed to work on the 1-1 with list items. But with code behind you can make it to do almost anything. Here is older example from SP2007 but with regards to IP not much has changed: [Submitting Data from InfoPath 2007 to a SharePoint List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc162745(v=office.12).aspx)